# Как получить базовый адрес процесса?

Tags: c++

Как можно получить базовый адрес процесса ?Никаких работающих примеров так и не нашел. Вот мой код

```
HWND hwnd;
    do {
    hwnd = FindWindowA(0,"Form1"); 
    Sleep(50); 
} while (!hwnd);
DWORD pid;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,pid);
```

Вызов функции

```
DWORD clientBase = getModuleBaseAddress(pid, "Form1.exe");
```

Функция

```
 DWORD getModuleBaseAddress(DWORD pid, const char* name)
    {
        HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid);
        MODULEENTRY32 mEntry;
        mEntry.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        do
        {
            if (!strcmp(mEntry.szModule, name))
            {
                CloseHandle(snapshot);
                return (DWORD)mEntry.modBaseAddr;
            }
        } while (Module32Next(snapshot, &mEntry));
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467229/get-base-address-of-process

Comment: Может тут подразумевается базовый адрес отображения исполняемого файла внутри адресного пространства процесса?

Comment: @VTT Не могу точно ответить. Я только начинаю изучать эту область. У меня есть написанная мной мини игра для тестов. Через IDA PRO я нашел оффсеты нужных мне данных. Теперь,если я все правильно понял,мне нужно найти базовый адрес для того что бы получить доступ к памяти через ReadMemory.А как его найти не совсем понятно

Comment: @VTT Я в конце вопроса добавил функцию с помощью которой я пытался получить базовый адрес,но все время получал 0. Может так будет проще разобраться

Comment: *нашел оффсеты нужных мне данных* - оффсеты относительно чего?

Comment: @VTT Относительно базового адреса

Comment: Так в IDA есть базовый адрес. Просто вбиваете его и всё. Как правило это `0x400000`. Плавающий базовый адрес только у библиотек.

Comment: А где обработка если `strcmp` не отработало? Может вы имя модуля неправильно пишите, не в том регистре например. Ф-ция регистро-чуствительная, попробуйте регистро-нечувствительную `stricmp`